# Disk mount on a linux VM , mounted elsewhere

Tags: linux, mount, virtual-machine, nfs

Hi I am using a slightly unnecessary(maybe?) kind of a set up ...

1. A debian build_VM
2. The build_VM ran out of space so I formatted and mounted a disk on to the build_VM
3. But before mounting the additional disk space , I was mounting my source directory(on my build_VM) on my local machine. Now , though the disk mount is under the source directory(and after mounting it to my local machine) , I am not able to see anything inside the new disk(though the top most folder inside the disk is visible).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No I have not mounted on top of an existing files/folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From build_VM, you will probably have to export the newly created and mounted filesystem. Then you'll probably have to mount that (possibly in a different location) on your "local machine".

In general this is a NFS thing not a VM thing. When you export a filesystem in NFS, you don't export other NFS mounted file systems underneath that.